# Echo out values of text-boxes created fia for loop in PHP

Tags: php, html, form-processing

I have the following form:
(please note I am aware that there are no validation in my code)

```
<form name="frmsplitter" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = 'step2.php'>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <select style="width: 80%" name="cobbulkamount">
                        <option>please select a bulk item</option>
                        <option value= 100>100</option>
                        <option value= 200>200</option>
                        </select>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Select number of items you want the bulk amount to be splited : </label><input type="text" name="txtnumberofitems" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['btnsplitItem'])){echo $_POST['txtnumberofitems'];}?>" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td><input type="submit" value="submit" name="btnsplitItem" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>           
    </form>`
```

the form submits it goes to the following page :

```
    <?php

    if (!empty($_POST['txtnumberofitems'])) {
        $bulkvalue = 200;
        $numberofitems = $_POST['txtnumberofitems'];
            echo "<form name='frmsplitter'  method='POST' action = 'step3.php'>";     
            echo "amount to be splited <input type='text' name='txtamountof' value =$numberofitems> ";
                for ($index = 0; $index < $numberofitems; $index++) {           
                    echo  "<table>".  
                    "<tr>
                    <td>|amount: <input type='text' name='txtamount.$index'/></td>
                    <td>|Reference 2: <input type='text' name='txtref.$index'/></td>
                    <td>|DCIP:<select name='cobdcip'.$index>
                    <option>DR</option>
                    <option>CR</option>
                    </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>";
                    }
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<input type='submit' name='btnpopulate' />";
                        echo "</form>";        
    }       
    ?>`
```

the form submits it goes to the following page :

```
        if (isset($_POST['btnpopulate'])) {
            $number = (int)$_POST['txtamountof'];
            for ($index = 0; $index < $number; $index++) {
                if (!empty($_POST['txtamount'.$index])) 
            { 
                    echo 'nooooooooooo';
            }
                else {                     
                        echo $_POST['txtamount'.$index];
                        echo '<br>';
                }   
            }
        } `
```

My problem is that I get the Notice: Undefined index: txtamount0 
and Notice: Undefined index: txtamount1

Comment: you may use "array_key_exists", to avoid any notice. If the problem is not the notice, but that you can't find the data  you wish, have you tried to echo the content of `$_POST` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your input is : `txtamount.1`, not `txtamount1`, so you should access it this way :

```
for ($index = 0; $index < $number; $index++) {
    if (array_key_exists('txtamount.'.$index, $_POST))  {
        [...]
```

Or change your html :

```
<td>|amount: <input type='text' name='txtamount$index'/></td>
```

Comment: Wow @Random thanks I feel stupid now for overthinking it a basic" ." making life difficult, just out of curiosity i tried to do make this entire project on one page is it possible or not ? If it is I want to try it

Comment: @Christiaan I can't see what you mean... "an entire project on one page" ?

Comment: What is the problem with that ?

Comment: I just want to know is it possible to put this example in one page without using more than one page ?

Comment: Well it depends on many things... it is a good practice to have a saparate file for a separate function. So one file to generate HTML, and one file managing the submit...